# Creating an SSRS table with data from two different database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting-services

-I have table A and table B in a database. 
-Table A contains a row for each user/customer, including a unique ID.
-Table B contains a row for each transaction that includes the user/customer ID associated with that transaction.

-I am wishing to create an SSRS table that, in column 1, contains all IDs/rows from table A.
-In column 2, I wish to display the count/number of transactions that each ID was associated with.

Could somebody please assist me in most efficiently designing a dataset and expressions for each column that would achieve this desired SSRS table?  Thank you tremendously!

Comment: Write a JOIN query that combines the date into one data set, then use _that_ as the grid's data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query as the dataset.

```
SELECT A.CustomerID, Count(1) AS TransactionCount
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B on A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
GROUP BY A.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thank you, though I apparently had to include A.CustomerID in the GROUP BY in order for it to work.

Comment: Good call, I forgot the group by - I've added it now.